# .EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES works only when made 'phony'

Tags: makefile

The [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html#Special-Targets) provides:

> '.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES'
>
> Simply by being mentioned as a target, this tells 'make' to export
>      all variables to child processes by default.  *Note Communicating
>      Variables to a Sub-'make': Variables/Recursion.

However, the following makefiles show that only by making `.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES` a **phony** target, then and **only** then, will it have the desired effect on the makefile, i.e. to export ALL variables.

Makefile(version 1) is:

```
ifeq "$(MAKELEVEL)" "0"

foo=bar

.DEFAULT:;

all: .EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES
    @$(MAKE)

else

all:
    @echo 'foo is: $(foo)'

endif
```

Running, we get:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/myname'
foo is:
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/myname'
```

Makefile(version 2) is:

```
ifeq "$(MAKELEVEL)" "0"

foo=bar

.DEFAULT:;

all: .EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES
    @$(MAKE)

# This line is added in THIS version.
.PHONY: .EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES

else

all:
    @echo 'foo is: $(foo)'

endif
```

Running, we get:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/myname'
foo is: bar
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/myname'
```

Now, the only difference between these 2 versions of makefile, is that in the 2nd version, the `.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES` was made phony.

Why is the 'phoniness' needed in order to work?

Answer (score 8):

> > Simply by being mentioned as a target,
>
> Why is the 'phoniness' needed in order to work?

It's not.  You didn't declare `.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES` as a target, you declared it as a prerequisite:

```
all: .EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES
```

That's a prerequisite, not a target.  If you declare it as a target:

```
.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES:
```

then it will work and you won't have to declare it phony.

A more accurate question would be, why does declaring `.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES` as phony work even though it's not declared as a target?  It happens because things that are marked phony are assumed to be targets even if they're not explicitly mentioned as such.  That may or may not be a bug, depending on how you interpret the intent of `.PHONY`.

Your questions recently seem to follow a pattern: read the documentation, then write a makefile that does something similar to but not the same as what the documentation says, observe it doesn't work as described, then ask why not.