# .ONESHELL target (a 'phony' target) has no effect on makefile

Tags: makefile

After establishing that [prerequisites to .PHONY are made target-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900167/export-all-variables-works-only-when-made-phony).

And looking at the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html#Special-Targets), where the following special targets seem to follow the **same** syntax rules:

> '.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES'
>
> ```
>  Simply by being mentioned as a target...
> ```
>
> ...
>   
>   ...
>   
>   ...
>
> '.ONESHELL'
>
> ```
>  If '.ONESHELL' is mentioned as a target...
> ```

I tried to following makefile:

```
all:
    @foo=bar
    @echo "foo=$${foo}"

.PHONY: all
.PHONY: .ONESHELL
```

By running it, and got:

```
foo=
```

Which definitely is not a result from "oneshell" execution.

So, are some `special variables` more *special* than others, regarding their syntax rules?

Comment: If the answers I've been providing on your questions are correct could you please accept them as such or post a comment letting me know what is still wrong?

Answer (score 3):

`.ONESHELL` should be provided as the **target** not as the prerequisite as you have specified in your question. If you specify `.ONESHELL: all` you should get the expected output of `foo=bar`. That is what I get when running `make` on the following `makefile`.

```
.ONESHELL: all
.PHONY: all

all:
    @foo=bar
    @echo "foo=$${foo}"
```

Comment: this is the answer indeed. 2018 and I can confirm this works still like charm

Comment: Specifying prerequisites doesn't limit the global scope of  `.ONESHELL` - it affects all recipes of `Makefile` (or none).